# Flex Crossdomain.xml file and FTP

Tags: apache-flex, sockets, ftp, crossdomain.xml

How do I use crossdomain with ftp?

I am trying to do a "hello world" level test of FTP in Flex, but for three days now, I cannot overcome the issue with how to coerce flex into accepting my crossdomain policy - even for testing purposes.
Here is my code:  The exact error text follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" initialize="onInitialize()" layout="vertical">

<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
  import mx.utils.*;
  import mx.controls.Alert;
  private var fileRef:FileReference;
  private var fileSize:uint;
  private var fileContents:ByteArray;
  //you need to initiate two scokets one for sending
  //commands and second for sending data to FTP Server
  //socket for sending commands to FTP
  private var s:Socket
  //responce from FTP
  private var ftpResponce:String;
  //socket for sending Data to FTP
  private var dataChannelSocket:Socket;
  //responce from FTP when sending Data to FTP
  private var dataResponce:String;
  //will hold the IP address of new socket created by FTP
  private var dataChannelIP:String;
  //will hold the Port number created by FTP
  private var dataChannelPort:int;
  private var user:String="I have the right user"; //FTP usernae
  private var pass:String="the pw is correct"; //FTP Password

  private function receiveReply(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    ftpResponce=s.readUTFBytes(s.bytesAvailable)
    var serverResponse:Number=Number(ftpResponce.substr(0, 3));
    if (ftpResponce.indexOf('227') > -1) {
      //get the ip from the string response
      var temp:Object=ftpResponce.substring(ftpResponce.indexOf("(") + 1
        , ftpResponce.indexOf(")"));
      var dataChannelSocket_temp:Object=temp.split(",");
      dataChannelIP=dataChannelSocket_temp.slice(0, 4).join(".");
      dataChannelPort=parseInt(dataChannelSocket_temp[4]) * 256 +
        int(dataChannelSocket_temp[5]);
      //create new Data Socket based on dataChannelSocket and dataChannelSocket port
      dataChannelSocket=new Socket(dataChannelIP, dataChannelPort);
      dataChannelSocket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, receiveData);
    }
    //few FTP Responce Codes
    switch (String(serverResponse)) {
      case "220":
        //FTP Server ready responce
        break;
      case "331":
        //User name okay, need password
        break;
      case "230":
        //User  logged in
        break;
      case "250":
        //CWD command successful
        break;
      case "227":
        //Entering Passive Mode (h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2).
        break;
      default:
    }
    //for more please
    //http://http://www.altools.com/image/support/alftp/ALFTP_35_help/
    //FTP_response_codes_rfc_959_messages.htm          
    traceData(ftpResponce);
  }

  private function receiveData(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    dataResponce=dataChannelSocket.readUTFBytes(
      dataChannelSocket.bytesAvailable);
    traceData("dataChannelSocket_response—>" + dataResponce);
  }

  private function showError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    traceData("Error—>" + e.text);
  }

  private function showSecError(e:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
    traceData("SecurityError–>" + e.text);
  }

  private function onInitialize():void {
    Security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.myUrlIsCorrectInMyProgram.com/crossdomain.xml");
  }

  private function createRemoteFile(fileName:String):void {
    if (fileName != null && fileName != "") {
      s.writeUTFBytes("STOR " + fileName + "\n");
      s.flush();
    }
  }

  private function sendData():void {
    fileContents=fileRef.data as ByteArray;
    fileSize=fileRef.size;
    dataChannelSocket.writeBytes(fileContents, 0, fileSize);
    dataChannelSocket.flush();
  }

  //initialize when application load
  private function upLoad():void {
    fileRef=new FileReference();
    //some eventlistener
    fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectEvent);
    fileRef.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, onFileOpen);
    //this function connects to the ftp server
    connect();
    //send the usernae and password
    this.userName(user);
    this.passWord(pass);
    //if you want to change the directory for upload file
    this.changeDirectory("/test/"); //directory name
    //enter into PASSV Mode
    s.writeUTFBytes("PASV\n");
    s.flush();
  }

  private function onFileOpen(event:Event):void {
  }

  private function traceData(event:Object):void {
    var tmp:String="================================\n";
    ta.text+=event.toString() + "\n";
    ta.verticalScrollPosition+=20;
  }

  private function ioErrorEvent(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
    Alert.show("IOError:" + event.text);
  }

  private function selectEvent(event:Event):void {
    btn_upload.enabled=true;
    filename.text=fileRef.name;
    fileRef.load();
  }

  private function uploadFile():void {
    createRemoteFile(fileRef.name);
    sendData();
  }

  private function connect():void {
    s=new Socket("ftp.myUrlIsCorrectInMyProgram.com", 21);
    s.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, receiveReply);
    s.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, showError);
    s.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, showSecError);
    s.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onSocketConnect);
    s.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onSocketClose);
    s.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, onSocketAtivate);
  }

  private function onSocketConnect(evt:Event):void {
    //traceData("OnSocketConnect–>"+evt.target.toString());
  }

  private function onSocketClose(evt:Event):void {
    //traceData("onSocketClose–>"+evt.target.toString());
  }

  private function onSocketAtivate(evt:Event):void {
    //traceData("onSocketAtivate–>"+evt.target.toString());
  }

  private function userName(str:String):void {
    sendCommand("USER " + str);
  }

  private function passWord(str:String):void {
    sendCommand("PASS " + str);
  }

  private function changeDirectory(str:String):void {
    sendCommand("CWD " + str);
  }

  private function sendCommand(arg:String):void {
    arg+="\n";
    s.writeUTFBytes(arg);
    s.flush();
  }
]]>
```

[SWF] /FTP-debug/FTP.swf - 739,099 bytes after decompression
Warning: Domain www.myUrlIsCorrectInMyProgram.com does not specify a meta-policy.  Applying default meta-policy 'master-only'.  This configuration is deprecated.  See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files to fix this problem.

Warning: Timeout on xmlsocket://ftp.myUrlIsCorrectInMyProgram.com:843 (at 3 seconds) while waiting for socket policy file.  This should not cause any problems, but see http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files for an explanation.

Warning: [strict] Ignoring policy file at xmlsocket://ftp.myUrlIsCorrectInMyProgram.com:21 due to incorrect syntax.  See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files to fix this problem.

*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to ftp.myUrlIsCorrectInMyProgram.com:21 halted - not permitted from `http://localhost/FTP-debug/FTP.swf`
Error: Request for resource at xmlsocket://ftp.myUrlIsCorrectInMyProgram.com:21 by requestor from `http://localhost/FTP-debug/FTP.swf` is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.

The "Information" at the URL's listed above is categorically unintelligable to me.

Please, someone help!

Comment: Did you manage to get your FTP client working? I'm trying to do something similar, but have trouble when it comes time to open a passive mode socket (see my question on the subject).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the crossdomain spec:

http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/64389123/CrossDomain_PolicyFile_Specification.pdf?version=1

This covers the warning you have and can help you get this working.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue but was able to fix it using the flash policy server that I downloaded from http://www.flash-resources.net/download.html. 
I ran this on the same machine that I have my tomcat server installed and made the call
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://:843");
from the application and it worked perfectly. No errors.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue but was able to fix it using the flash policy server that I downloaded from [here](http://www.flash-resources.net/download.html). 
I ran this on the same machine that I have my tomcat server installed and made the call
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://Machine Name:843");
from the application and it worked perfectly. No errors.

Watch the typo around the Machine Name in the last post.